# Creating a Main method tester

Tags: java

I am trying to create a tester method to display a list.
How do I create a CongressStats object to exercise printPartyBreakdownInSenate method?

```
package congress;
import java.util.List;






public class CongressMain {
  public static void main(String[] args){

     }
```

}

```
public class CongressStats
{
private int congressNum;

/**
 * Create a CongressStats object for the given congress number
 */
public CongressStats(int congressNum)
{
    this.congressNum = congressNum;
}

/**
 * Calculate and print the number of Democrats, Republicans, and Independents in this Senate
 */
public void printPartyBreakdownInSenate()
{
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok in your main function you would make an object of your class CongressStats.

```
public class CongressMain {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        CongressStats cs = new CongressStats(somenumhere);
        cs.printPartyBreakdown();  //call your function
    }
}
```

hopefully that helped.